# is it possible to use ruby to create the client side code for a web game?

Tags: ruby, web

i'm looking at creating a web game using html5 canvas and javascript.  i was wondering ,howerver, if it is possible to use ruby to create the client side code for a web game?  (i found one other question for this but it was over a year ago and hoping maybe there has been progress in this since then).

thanks in advance people of stackoverflow!

Comment: You'll need to expand a bit on that question. "Client" as in "browser side"? "Client" as in server-side but client of another process? Also, generally, yes, you can generate anything in anything.

Comment: i mean client as in browser side.  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean.
For the browser-side code, you will have to use JavaScript for drawing to your canvas and making AJAX requests to your webserver.

For the webserver-side code, it depends. If you are making a social/multiplayer game, you could probably code your entire game server as a RESTful JSON API in Ruby. If you absolutely have to interact with a server on another computer/process, just make sure that it exposes an interface that Ruby can interact with and code a Ruby JSON API on top of that.

If you are looking for a JavaScript alternative with Ruby-like syntax, check out CoffeeScript.